# Are the marginals of contingency tables created from archaeological site data fixed or unfixed?

Tags: contingency-tables, marginal-distribution

I am trying to understand the concept of fixed and unfixed marginals of contingency tables created out of human bone data retrieved from archaeological sites. When a site is excavated, by definition, it is destroyed so there is one and only one sample of human remains from that site.

Does that mean that a contingency table created from that sample has a 'fixed' total? Next, if I create a 2X2 contingency table where the rows are sex (males or females) and the columns are a specific pathological condition (present or absent), what is the status of the column frequencies, fixed or unfixed? Row frequencies? The more I think about this, the more muddled the concept becomes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question (after much reading). The overall size of the sample is not controllable as it would be in an experiment and/or sample survey/poll (i.e., it is unknown how many, if any, skeletons will be found during excavation). Similarly, the number of males and females is unknown (until evaluated after excavation) and the number of individuals with, or without, a pathological condition is unknown (again until evaluated after excavation). This means that any contingency table formed from these data would be categorized as 'unconditional' (i.e., neither the overall sample size, nor the rows or column frequencies are 'fixed' *in advance*). Given this, the 'best' test for independence in a 2X2 table is Bernard's test, and the 'best' test for larger tables is the repeated sampling chi-square test.

Have I got it right? Please comment one way or the other.